# Request UAC elevation in Go

Tags: windows, winapi, go, uac

Is there any way to elevate a new process or thread to administrator in Go?

It seems like `ShellExecute()` isn't available in Go and it isn't possible to elevate with `CreateProcess()`. I have no idea what else could be possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try and check the project [**w32**](https://github.com/AllenDang/w32): it has a [`shell32.go ShellExecute()`](https://github.com/AllenDang/w32/blob/299c95ad76ae3ba0df778ad37c081dde98425faf/shell32.go#L89) that could be useful.

> `w32` is a wrapper of windows apis for the Go Programming Language.
>
> It wraps win32 apis to "Go style" to make them easier to use.

---

Update 2020, since 2014, the package [`golang.org/x/sys/windows`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/sys/windows) does have a [`ShellExecute()`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/sys/windows#ShellExecute) function.

[Cliven](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8281441/cliven) mentions [Jeremy Black](https://github.com/jerblack)'s blog post "[Relaunch Windows Golang program with UAC elevation when admin rights needed](https://gist.github.com/jerblack/d0eb182cc5a1c1d92d92a4c4fcc416c6)"

- Jeremy first detects if the program is already running as admin by attempting to open `\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0` (per this [reddit suggestion](https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/53dthc/way_to_detect_if_the_programs_running_with/))

  ```golang
  _, err := os.Open("\\\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE0")
  ```
- Then Jeremy uses the `ShellExecute()` function, to call [`runas`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/cc771525(v=ws.11)) (described in "[Elevating During Runtime](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/320748/Elevating-During-Runtime)" from [Michael Haephrati](https://twitter.com/haephrati))

  ```golang
  func runMeElevated() {
      verb := "runas"
      exe, _ := os.Executable()
      cwd, _ := os.Getwd()
      args := strings.Join(os.Args[1:], " ")

      verbPtr, _ := syscall.UTF16PtrFromString(verb)
      exePtr, _ := syscall.UTF16PtrFromString(exe)
      cwdPtr, _ := syscall.UTF16PtrFromString(cwd)
      argPtr, _ := syscall.UTF16PtrFromString(args)

      var showCmd int32 = 1 //SW_NORMAL

      err := windows.ShellExecute(0, verbPtr, exePtr, argPtr, cwdPtr, showCmd)
      if err != nil {
          fmt.Println(err)
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: `SE_ERR_DDEBUSY`: [Claude](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claude_Debussy) would approve.

Comment: Thanks, just what I needed. Works like a charm. Btw: [gform, AllenDang's Windows GUI toolkit for Go,](https://github.com/AllenDang/gform) looks very useful, too.

Comment: When i add this code, Defender blocks the program!

Comment: @trueToastedCode 9 years later, it is possible Windows Defender might be picky with that kind of code. Even [simpler Go programs can trigger it](https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/s1bh01/goexecutables_and_windows_defender/).

Answer (score 0):

`CreateProcess()` does not support running elevated processes, but there is a third-party `CreateProcessElevated()` function in the following article that can:

[Vista UAC: The Definitive Guide](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19165/Vista-UAC-The-Definitive-Guide)

It also provides elevation versions of several other functions, including `CreateProcessAsUserElevated()` and `ShellExecuteElevated()`.